# Repetitive code find replace incrementally

Tags: excel, search, replace, find, notepad++

I have a set of 55 items. The 55 items consist of two rows, r1 and r2. The goal is to inject code above those two lines where, the only thing that will change is the label underscore (incrementally by 1). Then, I just need to close off the two rows with a closing tag `</radio>`.

Example: Consider this set of '3' items consisting of two rows each.

```
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">NEW! Try Med Remind</row>
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">Try Med Remind today</row>
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">Start Med Remind now</row>
```

The intended result:

```
<radio 
  label="q9_1"
  multicol:flow="horizontal"
  shuffle="rows"
  uses="multicol.7">
  <title>[pipe: q9txt]</title>
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">NEW! Try Med Remind</row>
</radio>
<radio 
  label="q9_2"
  multicol:flow="horizontal"
  shuffle="rows"
  uses="multicol.7">
  <title>[pipe: q9txt]</title>
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">Try Med Remind today</row>
</radio>
<radio 
  label="q9_3"
  multicol:flow="horizontal"
  shuffle="rows"
  uses="multicol.7">
  <title>[pipe: q9txt]</title>
  <row label="r1">Never miss a dose</row>
  <row label="r2">Start Med Remind now</row>
</radio>
```

Is this possible in Notepad++ or Excel (or a combination of the two). To get the list to this point, I used Excel concatenation and Notepad++ block selection.  But I seem to have hit a road block where I must do something repetitive and manual that may be automatic.

Comment: My colleague informed me that the builder accepts raw code in a single line and automatically parses it to multiple lines.  So this was solved using Excel concatenation.  However, I would like like to know the Notepad++ method for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can create a macro to do things that are manual and automate them.

In the View tab, click on Macros, then click Record Macro. Perform the action once, then click Stop Recording. I like to assign hotkeys to my recorded macros (although this may not be the best practice). I usually use ctrl+M.

While this is not a perfect automated solution, it may still potentially save you some time.

Comment: Do you have a good video tutorial that you use when you learned how to record macros, or can you make one and post a link to the video?

Comment: Perhaps try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwFd3vHCeo4 It really is fairly simple. Just click the "Record Macro" button, perform the action you want to repeat, and then "Stop Recording." It will then repeat the action you performed, starting from the cell you have selected.